# SortedList Doesn't taking multiple objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In SortedList, I am trying to add more then one objects but it's showing me error. Here I am attaching my code

```
SortedList sortedList = new SortedList()
{
    { "Ind", "India" },
    { "Inda", "India" },
    { "BD", "Bangladesh" },
    { "SA", "South Africa" },
    {"SL", "Sri Lanka" },
    {"UAE", "United of Arab Emirates" },
    {"USA", "United States of America" }
};
sortedList.Add("Hel", "Hello", "World");
```

Is there any way to add multiple objects in SortedList in C# language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=net-8.0#remarks):

> We don't recommend that you use the SortedList class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TKey,TValue> class. For more information, see Non-generic collections shouldn't be used on GitHub.

Then, the documentation stats that [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-8.0#examples) throws on attempting to add a duplicate **key**:

> The following code example creates an empty SortedList<TKey,TValue> of strings with string keys and uses the Add method to add some elements. The example demonstrates that the Add method throws an ArgumentException when attempting to add a duplicate key.

So as long as you can make the keys unique, it's fine. I don't see how in your case it can throw because your data doesn't have any duplicate keys. [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/anT3bQ)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sortedList = new SortedList<string, string>()
        {
            { "Ind", "India" },
            { "Inda", "India" },
            { "BD", "Bangladesh" },
            { "SA", "South Africa" },
            {"SL", "Sri Lanka" },
            {"UAE", "United of Arab Emirates" },
            {"USA", "United States of America" }
        };
        
        foreach (var (key, value) in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key + " " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They're probably talking about how they're having one too many arguments with `sortedList.Add("Hel", "Hello", "World");` (trying to add more than one value per key?)

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel oh I forgot about that line. Indeed there is no such overload that accepts 3 parameters.